# Problems launching command "sudo service apache2 status" in web server

Tags: apache, ubuntu, ssl-certificate, root, certbot

I comment my situation:

I joined a new job (first job), the issue is that I need to certify the SSL certificates of some web pages via Certbot, I have tried everything (Both on the web server and locally through Apache) and I have had many problems to be able to perform certification.

First of all, on the server when trying to use the "sudo" command, it gives me the following error:
internet:~# sudo service apache2 status
sudo: service: command not found

And secondly, when performing the certification at the "local" level, it gives me the following error:
root@-: # sudo certbot certonly --apache
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
Please enter the domain name(s) you would like on your certificate (comma and/or
space separated) (Enter 'c' to cancel): webmail.pacifik.cl
Requesting a certificate for webmail.-.cl

Certbot failed to authenticate some domains (authenticator: apache). The Certificate Authority reported these problems:
Domain: --------
Type: unauthorized
Detail: 190.121.-.- : Invalid response from http://webmail.-.cl/.well-known/acme-challenge/ -: 404

Hint: The Certificate Authority failed to verify the temporary Apache configuration changes made by Certbot. Ensure that the listed domains point to this Apache server and that it is accessible from the internet.

Some challenges have failed.
Ask for help or search for solutions at https://community.letsencrypt.org. See the logfile /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log or re-run Certbot with -v for more details.

Does anyone know how I can move forward?

Comment: Edit your question and include OS version, Apache version, Apache configuration file, VirtualHosts, etc. You must have Apache running correctly and know how it is configured before running certbot.

Comment: Edit your question and include OS version, Apache version, Apache configuration file, VirtualHosts, etc. You must have Apache running correctly and know how it is configured before running certbot.

I understand what you are telling me, the point is that within the PHP web server I cannot use the commands "sudo status", "sudo service" "su", etc, since I am logging in with root access and that I have it installed through apt-get the sudo command.

Do you have any other way to get in?

Comment: I don not understand "... other way to get in"